# How to send JavaScript to specific tab in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Thanks for helping.

Right now I am working on a chrome extension. I have an extension background script that uses a function to open new tabs in the browser to complete different 'tasks'. The function uses variables obtained from an api to decide the tab url and at what time to open it, etc.

Here is my function:

```
function NewTask(var1, var2, var3) { 
chrome.tabs.create({url: var1+var2+var3, active: false}, tab=>{
    tab.console.log(var5, var6)
})
```

}

As you can see, I try to console.log var5 and var6 on the new tab as an example. However, this does not work the way I intended. Is there a way I can pass the var5 and var6 variables through the function to the new tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the more confusing aspects of extensions. `chrome.tabs.create` is running in the "background" of the extension (where it has access to manipulate tabs by tabId)

So the callback you pass as the last parameter also runs in the background, to run javascript in a certain tab, you can use

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, { code: `console.log("I run in the tab, not the background!")` })
```

The code run in the tab is passed as a string, If you want to pass a variable from  the background script, you could do so like below (if the use of "`string ${variable}`" is confusing, check out [Expression interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals))

```
var urlFromBackground = "https://google.com"
var colorFromBackground = "rebeccapurple"
chrome.tabs.create({url: urlFromBackground, active: false}, tab=>{
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(
      tab.id,
      { code: `document.body.background = ${colorFromBackground}` }
    )
})
```